# Manually configuring a scheduling for learning rate in `pytorch_lightning`

Tags: pytorch-lightning

I would like to manually configure the learning rate scheduling using `pytorch_lightning` in the following way:

```
for epoch in range(0, 600):
            
   if (epoch + 1) % 200 == 0:
                
       for g in optimizer.param_groups:
                    
           g['lr'] *= 0.5
```

What I have tried is the following:

```
def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    
    X,y = batch
    
    preds = self.forward(X)
    
    loss = self.loss(preds,y)
    self.log('train_loss', loss, prog_bar=False)
    self.train_losses.append(loss)
    
    if self.current_epoch % 200 == 0 :
        
        opt = self.optimizers()[0]
    
    return loss
```

but I get back the following

```
TypeError: 'LightningAdamW' object is not subscriptable
```

EDIT:

I've simply found the solution by doing:

```
    if self.current_epoch % 200 == 0 :
        
        for g in self.optimizers().param_groups:
             
             g['lr']*=0.5
    
    return loss
```

My last perplexity is: is this something I should add in some Callback instead of leaving it directly into the training step?